# empty fields saves empty values in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that needs to be filled up by the user. It has required fields and others are not required. Example, the employee information fields are required to be filled up and the spouse, children and children birthdays aren't required. Whenever I tried to save data in the database while leaving the spouse and children empty it also saves an empty values in the database and the child birthday fields which are datepickers saves a default calendar value 1970-01-01. 
This is my php code for saving in the database.

```html
if (!empty($_POST['child']) && !empty($_POST['ch_DateOfBirth'])) {

        $selectEmp=$dbcon->query("Select Emp_ID from employee");
        $count=$selectEmp->num_rows;

        if ($count>0) {
                while($row=$selectEmp->fetch_array()){
                    $emp_id="".$row['Emp_ID']."";
                }

         $child_name=$_POST['child'];
         $count=count($child_name);

            for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) {
               $child_bday=date('Y-d-m', strtotime($_POST['ch_DateOfBirth'][$i]));
               $sql6="INSERT into  tbl_children (Emp_ID, Ch_Name, Ch_Bdate) values ('".$emp_id."', '".$child_name[$i]."', '".$child_bday."') ";
                $dbcon->query($sql6);
            }
        }

}
```

This is what the database displays.

[image]

Comment: set it to null.

Comment: Date has to be formatted in the  $child_bday=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['ch_DateOfBirth'][$i]));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_filter()` to remove null values from posted array.

```
$child_names = array_filter($_POST['child']);
foreach($child_names as $key => $child_name){

     $child_bday = (isset($_POST['ch_DateOfBirth'][$key]))?date('Y-d-m', strtotime($_POST['ch_DateOfBirth'][$key])):NULL;

     $sql6="INSERT into  tbl_children (Emp_ID, Ch_Name, Ch_Bdate) values ('".$emp_id."', '".$child_name."', '".$child_bday."') ";
            $dbcon->query($sql6);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Allow null values in your database i.e, set default value as `null`, for example,

```
`CREATE TABLE emptable(
`empname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`dob` date DEFAULT NULL);`
```

Answer (score 1):

The default calendar value is entered into the database because the empty value is converted to `1970-01-01` when you execute `date('Y-d-m', strtotime($_POST['ch_DateOfBirth']`.

So Check if the date is null and then convert it to the date format only if there is a value in it

```
for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) {
               $child_bday="";
               //converts to date format only if the date field is not empty..else its null
               if(!empty($_POST['ch_DateOfBirth'][$i])
               {
               $child_bday=date('Y-d-m', strtotime($_POST['ch_DateOfBirth'][$i]));
               }
               $sql6="INSERT into  tbl_children (Emp_ID, Ch_Name, Ch_Bdate) values ('".$emp_id."', '".$child_name[$i]."', '".$child_bday."') ";
                $dbcon->query($sql6);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly : You Need to alter your table column "Ch_Bdate"

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE `Ch_Bdate` `Ch_Bdate` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```